# How to distinctly select tables with different row and column count in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I am doing a project that involves mysql and I am using tables with different number of column and row. Now I want to select everything from table1 - this contains multiple rows and columns together with table2 that has only 3 columns and 1 row. I tried using

```
Select * from table1,table2
```

but the result repeats the row in table2 equal to the row count of table1.

Comment: You have to use `UNION`. For more help you have to add the table description.

Comment: i tried using union but an error occurred. it says Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

table1 contains 6 columns and variable number of rows because it is  to be filled by my program. then table2 has 3 columns and 1 row only.

Answer (score 0):

Use "UNION":

```
Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 from table1
UNION
Select col1,col2,col3,null,null,null from table1
```